# Facebook login popup issues

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So im developing an app that needs some extra permissions from Facebook.  I have a button that requests permissions and with a callback executes some function.  The problem im running in is that if user allready gave permissions and is clicking the buton again that login popup still comes up and instantly closes.  I found a way to check if user has permissions before executing FB.login command (witch makes this popup appear only if user doesn't have permissions) but i then run into popup blocker issue because i am putting the FB.login call into the else statement of that check.

As i understand the FB.login has to be in same flow of the function to avoid popup blockers.

Here is my code:

```
$('#shareList').click(function (event) {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function (data) {
        if (data.data[0].photo_upload == 1) {
            $.uploadPic();
            //return false;
            //event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            $.uploadPic();
        } else {
            alert('Tekkis viga');
        }
    }, {scope:'photo_upload'});

    return false;
});
```

Ideally i would like to stop the function if it falls into that check of `photo_upload` check and proceed to login call.  I did try both return false and event.stopPropagation() but they don't seem to work.  What could be the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is **getLoginStatus**, which will construct the Facebook session for a user who is already authenticated/logged-in...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Actually its not really what i am looking for because i am not checking for login status but for permissions.